# Pyserial using default system serial configuration

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

When initializing serial connection using python pyserial without any baud-rate,  It goes to the default 9600 baud configuration

> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')

Does this pyserial have any option that it read / write to the serial port with the already configured settings that which configured through another application or **stty**  linux command ?

Comment: Could you please clarify your question by adding more details as an explanation? I did not get, what you're asking...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've investigated pySerial's source code. It seems this is not possible. PySerial has a set of defaults. And if I'm not mistaken, when you call `open()` method it will always configure port to these defaults or whatever setting you changed them to.

This is the relevant bit from the implementation of `Serial::open()` method:

```
def open(self):
    """\
    Open port with current settings. This may throw a SerialException
    if the port cannot be opened."""

    # ... ...

    # open
    try:
        self.fd = os.open(self.portstr, os.O_RDWR | os.O_NOCTTY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    except OSError as msg:
        self.fd = None
        raise SerialException(msg.errno, "could not open port %s: %s" % (self._port, msg))
    #~ fcntl.fcntl(self.fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, 0)  # set blocking

    try:
        # **this is where configuration occurs**
        self._reconfigure_port(force_update=True)
    except:
        try:
            os.close(self.fd)
        except:
            # ignore any exception when closing the port
            # also to keep original exception that happened when setting up
            pass
        self.fd = None
        raise
    else:
```

https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialposix.py#L299

I see two alternatives for you; get the settings that you are interested from the system (using `stty` maybe) before calling `Serial::open()` and set these settings explicitly.

Another option is to subclass PySerial's `Serial` class, re implement `::open()` method, skip the configuration part:

```
    # self._reconfigure_port(force_update=True)
```

I'm not sure if that would work though. It may cause problems, because other parts of the implementation are expecting port to be in a specific configuration, but it isn't.

UPDATE: I think a better implementation of `open()` method would read the settings from the opened port and set necessary attributes/properties of the `Serial` object to reflect these settings.